# How do I introduce a quoted clause within an independent clause?

Tags: punctuation, commas, sentence, quotation-marks, colons

How do we introduce a quoted clause within an independent clause?
For example, when talking about why we say, "John passes away or passed away." How do we write it in a sentence?

My sentence starts off as the following:

1. We normally say "John has passed away or John passed away."
   Or I should write it as follows?
2. We normally say, "John has passed away, or John passed away," rather than "John passes away."

Do we use a comma before John, or colon, or do we write it as in sentence #1?

Comment: You'd use a comma after "say," but that doesn't mean number 1 is necessarily correct. I think what you might want to say is: We normally say, "John has passed away," or, "John passed away."

Comment: I think we don't use "John passes away" because it is simple present and that is only used for events in general which keep on occuring. In present, we can say "John has passed away", but "John passed away" is more close to the sense. (Can you write this sentence by pointing my mistakes in it?)

Comment: Whether or not to use a comma, a colon, or zero punctuation before opening quotes has been discussed before. Hyperprescriptivists will still no doubt disagree with the modern trends. Here, I think the running flow makes the commas infelicitous. I'd use << We normally say "John has passed away" or "John passed away", rather than "John passes away". >> Again, some might insist on the old prescriptivist comma after the first _away_.